# Keep object reference in recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, lodash

I have an application where an object is used to display a tree view of files on a user's system. It's structured like so:

```
[{
   text: 'C:/',
   type: 'dir',
   nodes: [
      {
         text: 'foo',
         type: 'dir',
         nodes: [] // And so on
      },
      {
         text: 'bar',
         type: 'file'
      }
}]
```

In keeping with conventions, I'd like directories to be displayed first and files to be displayed second. Unfortunately, my data is retrieved in alphabetical order regardless of item type.

To remedy this I wrote a nice recursive function

```
var sort = function (subtree)
{
   subtree = _.sortBy(subtree, function (item)
   {
      if (item.nodes)
      {
         sort(item.nodes)
      }
      return item.type
   });
}

var tree = someTreeData;
sort(tree);
```

I'm using lodash to sort each of the `nodes` arrays alphabetically by file type. Unfortunately the subtree does not appear to reference the tree object as when I log its output it remains unsorted. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaScript’s built-in `Array.prototype.sort` function, which does sort in-place. It accepts two arguments and performs a comparison. Note that sorting `item.notes` inside the `sortBy` key extractor is kind of inappropriate.

```
function isDirectory(node) {
    return !!node.nodes;
}

function sortTree(subtree) {
    subtree.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.type < b.type ? -1 :
               a.type > b.type ? 1 : 0;
    });

    subtree
        .filter(isDirectory)
        .forEach(function (node) {
            sortTree(node.nodes);
        });
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly with a slight modification ``.forEach(function (node) { sortTree(node.nodes) });``